# How to use one of the results of a parametric function as a new function with the parameters as variable

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions

I would like to use the result of a parametric equation as a new function of the parameters. Given the solutions of the following

```
s = NSolve[c^(bt + 1) - h*(bt + 1)*c^bt - (bt + 1)*y == 0, c]
```

I'd like to have a function

```
f[y_,h_]:=h+(h^2+2y)^0.5
```

which is the second solution of the polynomial equation in the NSolve method for `bt=1` 
I'm new with mathematica, I tried with `c/.s[[2]]` but it doesn't seem to recognize the result as a function.
Thanks
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Clear[f, h, y];
f[h_, y_] := Solve[c^(bt + 1) - h (bt + 1) c^bt - (bt + 1) y == 0 /. bt -> 1, c]
Integrate[c /. f[0, y][[2]], {y, 0, 1}]
```

I think it is what interests you.

Comment: Almost. The problem now is that one of the two arguments (h,y) is set to zero. The function is also the argument of an integral over the y variable, and in this case doesn't seams to work, even though, if I write the function manually in the integral, I will not have any problems. Thanks